# Sql Query with Date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to fetch records from the table using the below sql query.

```
SELECT Code,Description FROM Table
WHERE ID= 1 AND FromDate >= '2010-02-14' AND ToDate <= '2012-03-14'
```

Even though records exists for this date, query returns nothing.

```
ID HID HCode HDescription FromDate            ToDate 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1  3   H8    New Year     2012-03-14 12:38:00 2012-03-14 12:38:00
```

Please give me a suitable solution. Thanks for your time !!

Comment: Can you post your table design?

Comment: Can you show us the `FromDate` and `ToDate` for the record with `ID=1`?

Comment: To be independent of any language, regional or date format settings, you should use the ISO-8601 format when specifying dates - `YYYYMMDD` (**no** dashes!). Also: if those are `DATETIME` oclumns (you didn't clearly say so), then `<= '20120314'` will find anything *before* the 14th of March - but if will **not** read any entries for the 14th of March (with a time portion > 00:00:00) ....

Comment: @marc_s both YYYY-MM-DD or YYYYMMDD are ISO8601. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: @RoyiNamir - `YYYY-MM-DD` is safe for `date` but not for `datetime`. Have a look [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/wishlist.html#YYYYMMDD).

Comment: @MikaelEriksson yep. the answer of mine was in regards to : " both of these formats are in 8601".

Comment: Something that I've found is when you want to work with dates as a string value, use the date the format like `dd MMM yyyy` eg 19 Mar 2012

Comment: @RoyiNamir: **NO THEY ARE NOT** - try this:  `set language british;  select CAST('2012-03-31' AS DATETIME)` and you'll get an error: `Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 3
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.`

Comment: @MikaelEriksson your article link talks about MySql and Not Sql Srver...

Comment: @RoyiNamir - You've misread (as I almost did). It says My *SQL Server* Wishlist, not *My SQL* Server Wishlist.

Comment: Pls find the record entry below                                                         ID HID HCode HDescription FromDate  ToDate   
1 3 H8 New Year 2012-03-14 12:38:00 2012-03-14 12:38:00

Comment: @Colin - Table Design                                                                 ID  int 
HID  int 
HCode  nvarchar(15) 
HDescription nvarchar(50) 
HFrom  smalldatetime 
HTo  smalldatetime

Comment: @RoyiNamir: yes - that's the *long* ISO-8601 format (date and time portions). There's also the *short* (date-only) format - but for that to work **reliably** regardless of whatever language settings your SQL Server has, you must use `YYYYMMDD` **WITHOUT** any dashes. I know this goes against what Wikipedia says about ISO-8601 - but that's the **REALITY** of SQL Server as it exists today. Get used to it.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - the `T` is what makes that safe. Remove the `T` and it will fail.

Comment: @marc_s Im not arguing with you. Im just saying that your example werent accurate and had unused `set language`. Also - please notice that The SHORT way is ISO and not ISO8601 as you stated. and to remind you weve talked about ISO8601 and not ISO. http://i.stack.imgur.com/9muVt.jpg ...

Comment: @MikaelEriksson MSDN explictly say that you should write EACH ELEMENT. So why you want to remove the T ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir - I have not suggested that you should remove it. I said that **IF** you remove it you will have trouble with certain locale settings. There are two ways to make a string literal safe for implicit conversion to `datetime`. `YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS` or `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS`. When you don't want to specify the time part you must use `YYYYMMDD`.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: check this page - [MSDN SQL Server 2008 R2 docs on DATETIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) - when you scroll down to about the middle of the page, it lists valid "ISO-8601" formats - and both `YYYYMMDD` as well as `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` are listed .....

Comment: @MikaelEriksson Thanks. I was thinking  : What if i want the ISO format but with TIME ? is it correct ? ( it is working) but is it the correct ver ?  select `CAST('201203 13:13:13' AS DATETIME)`

Comment: @marc_s Thanks I will read it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
declare @dayAfter datetime     --let take 1 day after

set @dayAfter = DateAdd(day,1,'20120314')

SELECT Code,Description FROM Table
WHERE ID= 1 AND 
FromDate >= '20100214' AND 
ToDate <  DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, @dayAfter ), 0)
```

p.s :

`DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, @dayAfter ), 0)` will reset time to `00:00`

so you need  `desired EndTime < begining of the day after`

Comment: @SyedIbrahim youre welcome. please also read the conversation between me and marc and mikael. there were some important points to notice about. ( and learn [also for me])

Answer (score 1):

Try with following query,it will definately solve your problem....

```
SELECT Code,Description FROM Table
   WHERE ID= 1 AND
         CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), FromDate, 101)>= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST('2010-02-14' AS DATETIME),101) AND 
         CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ToDate, 101)<= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST('2012-03-14' AS DATETIME),101) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you select data between FromDate and ToDate then remove ID=1.
Аs in this case is selected record with ID = 1 and FromDate and ToDate checked this entry.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting data from ragne

```
FromDate >= '2010-02-14 00:00:0000' AND ToDate <= '2012-03-14 00:00:0000'
```

You should do like this:

```
FromDate >= '2010-02-14' AND ToDate < '2012-03-15'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
 FROM  table
 WHERE year_date BETWEEN FromDate AND ToDate
```